# Changing graphics driver in Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, amd-graphics, radeon

I have a [Debian Stretch](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch) laptop with two graphics controllers:

```
[0]~>lspci | fgrep 'VGA compatible controller' 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Pro Graphics P580 (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev 83)
```

Now the Intel controller seems to be used for GLX rendering:

```
[0]~>glxinfo | fgrep Device:
Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Iris Pro Graphics P580 (Skylake GT4e)  (0x193d)
[0]~>glxgears -info | fgrep GL_RENDERER
GL_RENDERER   = Mesa DRI Intel(R) Iris Pro Graphics P580 (Skylake GT4e)
[0]~>glmark2 | fgrep GL_RENDERER:
GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) Iris Pro Graphics P580 (Skylake GT4e)
```

These modules are loaded:

```
[0]~>fgrep LoadModule: /var/log/Xorg.0.log 
[    10.301] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    10.312] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    10.312] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[    10.314] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    10.315] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    10.316] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    10.349] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    10.350] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    10.987] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    10.988] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    10.988] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    10.988] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    12.980] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    13.195] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
```

I have **no** X.Org configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

How can I configure X.Org to use the AMD controller?

Comment: I see the X server has autodetected the AMD controller, since it has loaded the `radeon` module. Please post the output of `xrandr --listproviders` and `xrandr` with no parameters - let's find out how your laptop display hardware is configured. Also please see: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/gpu/vga-switcheroo.html

Comment: See xrandr results here: https://pastebin.com/nTvjn6TT

Answer (score 1):

Cool, both your GPU drivers can handle both output source/sink and render offload source/sink operations. So... try this:

```
xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink "VERDE @ pci:0000:01:00.0" "modesetting"
```

or by using provider numbers:

```
xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 1 0
```

This tells the Intel controller to offload its rendering tasks to the AMD GPU. It is not as efficient as switching the outputs to the AMD GPU, but it's the easiest way to make use of both your GPUs with your current configuration.

If it works for you, put that command into a script in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` directory, for example `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/15custom_xrandr`:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr -setprovideroffloadsink "VERDE @ pci:0000:01:00.0" "modesetting"
```

If you have the `debugfs` virtual filesystem mounted at `/sys/kernel/debug` and `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/` directory exists, you may be able to switch the outputs to the AMD GPU's control, if your hardware includes the required multiplexer chip. It should be as easy as arranging something to run

```
echo "DIS" >>/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

before starting the X server. Then the X server should automatically detect that all the active displays are now on the AMD GPU, and should leave the Intel GPU alone.

Comment: I've tried all of these with X restart and pc reboot: `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink ...`, `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 1 0` and `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/15custom_xrandr` (with double hyphen in xrandr switch). However, `glxgears -info` always reports using Intel GL renderer.

Comment: I decided to disable Intel graphics from BIOS. Now `glxgears -info` reports using GL renderer `Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAPE VERDE (DRM 2.49.0 / 4.9.0-5-amd64, LLVM 3.9.1)`.

Comment: Please @haba713 post your answer if it was useful to you(at the same time you are sharing with the rest of Stack community, that's the idea about this website), and mark it as right! Thanks!